# REST API delete HTTP request in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, http-delete

I'm learning REST API. I'm trying to delete an element from the list. I tried but getting an error on the postman. Can anyone help me where I went wrong?
Also, can we return the object after deleting it? I also tried it but I think I'm messing up in delete code. So it was not working.

****Here is the controller code:****

```
@RestController
public class SpringRestController {
    
@Autowired
private CourseService courseService;

//Get the courses
@GetMapping("/courses")
public List<Course> getCourses()
{
    return this.courseService.getCourses();
}

@GetMapping("/courses/{courseId}")
public Course getCourse(@PathVariable String courseId)
{
    return this.courseService.getCourse(Long.parseLong(courseId));
}

//Add a course
@PostMapping("/courses")
public Course addCourse(@RequestBody Course course)
{
    return this.courseService.addCourse(course);
}

@PutMapping("/courses/{courseId}")
public Course updateCourse(@PathVariable String courseId,@RequestBody Course course)
{
    return this.courseService.updateCourse(Long.parseLong(courseId),course);
}

@DeleteMapping("/courses/{courseId}")
public List<Course> deleteCourse(@PathVariable String courseId)
{
    return (List<Course>) this.courseService.deleteCourse(Long.parseLong(courseId));    
    
}
}
```

**Here is the service implementation of the request :**

```
@Service
public class CourseServiceImpl implements CourseService {

List<Course> list;

public CourseServiceImpl()
{
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Course(145l,"Java Array","Basic Array"));
    list.add(new Course(123l,"Java Constructor","Basic Constructor"));
}

@Override
public List<Course> getCourses() {
    return list;
}

@Override
public Course getCourse(long courseId) {
    Course c = null;
    for(Course course:list)
    {
        if(course.getId()==courseId)
        {
            c=course;
            break;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

@Override
public Course addCourse(Course course) {
    list.add(course);
    return course;
}

@Override
public Course updateCourse(long courseId,Course course) {
    Course c = null;
    for(Course cour:list)
    {
    if(cour.getId()==courseId)
    {
        cour.setTitle(course.getTitle());
        cour.setDescription(course.getDescription());
        c=cour;
    }
    }   
    return c;       
}

@Override
public List<Course> deleteCourse(long courseId) {
    
    for(Course course:list)
    {
        if(course.getId()==courseId)
        {           
            list.remove(course);
        }
    }       
    return list;        
}
}
```

**No errors in spring boot.**

**Error I got in postman is here :**

```
{
"timestamp": "2021-07-13T03:36:27.454+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"path": "/courses/786"
}
```

Comment: Can you ping the errors

Comment: After deletion also we can return whatever.

Comment: There's not enough information in your question for anyone to help you. Please post the error text from postman and any logs from your server. Have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and or [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This is the error in postman : `{
    "timestamp": "2021-07-13T03:36:27.454+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/courses/786"
}`

Comment: This error from postman ping the error from console.

Comment: No error from console. When I'm sending a delete request postman gives that error. I think I'm messing up in the delete method.

Comment: Hey sorry. This is the first time I'm posting a question. Thank you for responding sir

Comment: No problem, 500 internal server error is most likely an uncaught exception thrown on the server. Is there a logger implementation in your spring boot app writing a log file in your target directory or wherever you're running your spring boot app from?

Comment: No logger implementation. I'm just learning how to make API. I'm also not working with JPA or DB, just making request in local list.

Comment: Can you run it in a debugger and put a break point on your controller delete method?

Comment: Can you share your complete controller file. Seems like error is in initialization of courseServiceImpl object.

Comment: I will run it with a debugger.

Comment: Edited and added the whole controller code .

Comment: Is your other API working fine?

Comment: Yes all API working fine. I will also add the code of other API.

Comment: Remove the casting in deletion return no need.

Comment: Check my answer below you can not remove. like object use iterator.

Comment: It will work and give vote if works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your Code, **foreach** cannot used to remove **item**, you should use **Iterator**.

```
for (Iterator<Course> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Course course = iterator.next();
    if (course.getId() == courseId) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote. But Thank you very much sir. Can you tell me the reason why we this method?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the object using index not like object. That the issue.

```
list.remove(index of the object);


Iterator<Object> li = list;

While(li.hasNext()){
 Object obj= li.next();
 If(courseId==id){
 Ii.remove();
 }
}
```

Comment: I need at least 15 reputations to cast a vote. But Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass courseId as "786" which is not present in your ArrayList. If you still want to delete it, then add a course with courseId "786" in your Course list.

When I tried deleting course with id 786 it shows all other courses because courseId 786 is not present in the list.

Answer (score -1):

Check course id 786 is present in your list or not.

Comment: I implemented an post http request also that's workiing fine. I added course with 786 course id , then I was trying to delete the same course with id 786 just to check if its deleting or not

Comment: If courseId present or not that's not issue